# iOS App: Segmented control for Login/Signup screens

Tags: ios, mobile-application

I am planning UX for an app and currently working on Login/Signup screens. Looking at some various other app screens, it looks like the most common is to make welcome screens with both options - Login and Signup, from where it is possible to navigate to one of them, but I am thinking, would that be a good solution in terms of iOS development to make segmented control for these screens? I think it would be a great UX to be able to navigate between these screens in just one tap. Can anyone advise me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need something unique using which you identity if the user is loggiing in or signing up! So for that what you can do is ask for email Id.

Then identify if user is already registered then show login page with already showing entered email id so only user need to generate password.

Or Sign up screen where you can show entered email id, along with ask to reenter it to confirm the new email Id.

[image]